# How to extract href value from rel tag in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
...html...
<link rel="image_src" href="image.jpg" />
....more html....
```

How to extract the image url using BeautifulSoup in Python

Comment: `soup.find('link')['href']` ?

Comment: @furas no there are a lot of <link code, need to filter out with rel and also this html part is outside of any div tag

Comment: then use `find_all()` - `for item in find_all('link'):` prin(item['href'])`

Comment: @furas I would want that one specif url

Comment: then use more options in `find_all` - like `{'href': True, 'rel': 'image_src'}`. Or if this link is in other unique tag then first find this tag and later search inside this tag.

Comment: it exists on an independent line

Comment: Beautifulsoup doesn't care if it is in indenpende line. You have to find some tag to limit it. So you should show more HTML in question because current question is incomplet. You only ask how to get image url from this HTML and you got many answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find()` or `find_all()`  for more items

```
for item in soup.find_all('link'): 
     print(item['href'])`
```

You can also use `{href': True}` to make sure that link will have `href`. And `{'rel': 'image_src'}` to make sure that it is link with image.

```
for item in soup.find_all('link', {'href': True, 'rel': 'image_src'}): 
     print(item['href'])`
```

---

Minimal working example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''
    <link rel="image_src" />
    <link rel="image_src" href="image1.jpg" />
    <link rel="sound_src" href="hello.mp3" />
    <link rel="image_src" href="image2.jpg" />
'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('link', {'href': True, 'rel': "image_src"}):
    print(item['href'])
```

Comment: okay, I did with find, and I have the solution here, with the image_url.attrs['href']

Combining yours and @Wonka answer

Comment: my code also use `['href']` - so it also gives url :)

Answer (score 2):

If `soup` is the `BeautifulSoup` object, then use

```py
hrefs = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('link') if link.get('href') is not None]
```

Beware that there might not be a `href` attribute, and in that case, `link['href']` will raise `KeyError`. This is why I used `link.get('href')` to check existence.

If you want to find `link`s with `rel="image_src"`, use

```py
hrefs = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('link', {'rel': 'image_src'}) if link.get('href') is not None]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
links = soup.find_all("link", {"rel": True})
for link in links:
    print(link.attrs["href"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Css selector this.

```
soup.select_one('[rel="image_src"]')['href']
```

OR

```
 soup.select_one('link[rel="image_src"]')['href']
```

For multiple items.

```
for item in soup.select('[rel="image_src"]'):
    print(item['href'])
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd one, `NoneType Error: object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @johnrao07 : The code should work fine if your soup contains the tag and attribute you have posted?

Comment: Yes, @furas solution came the closest here

Comment: I am using beautifulsoup 4.7 which support css selector.may the reason